# Mysql index not work on higher limits

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, primary-key

I have a table that contain one primary key.
When I run

**EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 29**

Mysql returns

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE           news    ALL      NULL           NULL    NULL      NULL     640     Using filesort
```

But by **EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM news
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 28** 
it returns

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          news    index   NULL           PRIMARY  4          NULL     28
```

SHOW INDEX FROM news ;

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment  
'news', 0, 'PRIMARY', 1, 'id', 'A', 640, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
'news', 1, 'tarix', 1, 'tarix', 'A', 106, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
'news', 1, 'yayindil', 1, 'yayin', 'A', 3, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
'news', 1, 'yayindil', 2, 'dil', 'A', 7, , '', '', 'BTREE', ''
```

I checked it on other tables, they work fine also on limit 4000. What is going wrong? Why only under 29 limitations use indexes?

Comment: How many rows does that table have?

Comment: Are the indexes similar in both tables ? See the `show index from news` output.

Comment: really strange, are you sure of query?, try escaping names with ``

Comment: I add SHOW INDEX FROM news ; by editing my post. changing limit valuse affect key uasage.

Comment: All limit counts greater than 28 fail to use the index ? It's weird, but at least this would not imply in bad performance given the amount of rows (640).

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945925/mysql-index-being-ignored

Comment: FORCE INDEX is not working. In local there is 640 rows but on server it is more than 40000 records on table. All limit counts greater than 28 fail to use the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimiser is trying to select the cheapest execution path. With only 640 rows in the table it isn't strange that the optimiser chooses a full scan. Load the table with 40000 rows and you will find that you have to increase the limit (probably to around 2000) before a full table scan is chosen.